# How can I create a function that loops through a vector and provides me with a vector of only Ns in sampleN.TOST in R?

Tags: r, list, function, loops

I created a function that loops over three different power scenarios with a specific CV%, but cannot get it to spit out only the Ns in a list (see below):

```
pwr.vec = c(0.80,0.85,0.90)

sample.3.cross = function(x, pwr.vec){

  for (i in pwr.vec){
    result = list()

    sample.size = sampleN.TOST(CV = x, design = "3x3", targetpower = i, theta0 = 1.11)[['Sample size']]

    result[i] = list(sample.size)

  }
  return(data.frame(result))
}
```

I have tried modifying the function countless ways, to no end. When I run the function, I get the following output.

```
sample.3.cross(.23,pwr.vec)

data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

I just need the three Ns in a simple list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. You should create list `result` outside of for loop
2. Note your `i`is 0.80,0.85,0.90, not 1,2 and 3. This means `result[i]` does not work the way you intended.

Fix these two issues would yield the result:

```
library(PowerTOST)
pwr.vec = c(0.80,0.85,0.90)

sample.3.cross = function(x, pwr.vec){
  result = list()
  for (i in seq_along(pwr.vec)){
    pwr <- pwr.vec[i]
    

    sample.size = sampleN.TOST(CV = x, design = "3x3", targetpower = pwr, theta0 = 1.11)[['Sample size']]


    result[i] = list(sample.size)

  }
  return((result))
}

sample.3.cross(.23,pwr.vec)

[[1]]
[1] 48

[[2]]
[1] 54

[[3]]
[1] 66
```

Comment: A million thanks for this! Now I can move forward to create a table within my function!